# How to access plpgsql composite type array components

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Let's say I've created a composite type in Postgresql:

```
CREATE TYPE custom_type AS
   (x integer
    y integer);
```

I need to use it in a function as an array:

```
...
DECLARE
customVar custom_type[];
BEGIN
....
```

My question is: how do I access custom_type's specific components?

For example, I want to (re)assign 'x' for the third element in custom_type array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
postgres=> create type pt as (x int, y int);
CREATE TYPE

postgres=> create or replace function fx()
returns void as $$
declare a pt[] = ARRAY[(10,20),(30,40)]; declare xx pt;
begin
  for i in array_lower(a, 1) .. array_upper(a,1)
  loop
    xx = a[i]; xx.x := xx.x + 1; a[i] := xx; raise notice '%', a[i].x;
  end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
postgres=> select fx();
NOTICE:  11
NOTICE:  31
 fx 
────

(1 row)
```

Significant limit for target of assign statement is possibility to refer only one level nested properties. This limit can be bypassed by auxiliary variables - it is not too friendly - and internal implementation is too simple, but it is fast and enough for typical stored procedure usage although it is not strong in comparison with generic programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
SELECT ARRAY[(1,2),(3,4)]::custom_type[];
```

Use an array subscript and then refer to the field by name.

```
regress=> SELECT (ARRAY[(1,2),(3,4)]::custom_type[])[1].x;
 x 
---
 1
(1 row)
```

Comment: It works for read purposes, but how do I reassign the element?

Comment: @MaxGruzin You don't in ordinary SQL. Arrays aren't mutable. You create a new array. In procedural SQL (PL/PgSQL) I think you can assign it with `:=` ... but I'm not sure. Try it.